# IC Design Resources

Tags: integrated-circuit, cmos

Looking for some resources on the design of Integrated Circuit Designs as they can contain a range of components. I am interested in how they can produce diodes and resistors on the dies in the ICs. Are there any free resources available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're looking for a free IC design book available on the web, I would recommend Hans Camenzind's book *[Designing Analog Circuits](http://www.designinganalogchips.com)*. It's a pretty good resource that goes from the device building blocks to the large complicated circuits. It has plenty of drawings and is much more readable than any textbook I have.

His text is not encyclopedic, but you should be able to get enough examples to understand **A** way to build a diode so that you wouldn't be shocked by a new method.